# php-cli require_once() failing on ubuntu works on mac

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am working with the voip.ms php api I wish to run a php script from the cli it works fine on my mac in terminal but on the ubuntu server it fails...

the script:

```
<?php
require_once("class.voipms.php");
$voipms = new VoIPms();
...
```

the begining of class.voipms.php

```
<?
class VoIPms{
...
```

the error

first it spits out 2000+ lines from class.voipms.php then

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'VoIPms' not found in /root/voipreg/check.php on line 3
```

obviously the class is in class.voipms.php and the script can find class.voipms.php because it gets printed to the cli and everything runs fine from terminal on my mac so I am rather confused!

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP short tags (just `<?` vs the full tag `<?php`) are likely disabled on the Ubuntu system. I would suggest not using short tags as they are not enabled everywhere like the full tag is. If not enabled, you will get exactly what you are describing. PHP doesn't recognize the file as code and just spits it out as text.

While you can enable the short tags in php.ini, I would suggest just not using it. You can't rely on it being enable everywhere and it's not like it is that hard to just type out the full thing. You can also still use the short echo tag `<?=`, even with short tags disabled, for a while now.

Comment: That was it, now i have functions in the class.voipms.php file failing with class not found is there a lot of things i should expect to not work going from mac to ubuntu?

Comment: Sounds like a different issue that depends on what classes aren't found (built in vs user defined). The differences between the two and your code are most likely just the extensions installed. If those matched up, the code should still run. Very little in php is platform specific. And that would usually only be between windows and some *nix system.

Comment: :-( they are all user defined

Comment: Well, either check that all the files use the full php tag, not the short one (and not just in the top of the file if the file goes in/out of php at all) or enable the short tags as a quick fix to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The class file specified is not able to be found.  The way to specify the file, it is expecting it to be in either the same directory this script is being run from, or some one of the directories in you PHP include path.

Perhaps you have different include paths configured in the different environments if the class file is truly not in the same directory as this script.